# Trying to Change Bibliography/References Header

Tags: biblatex, naming

I am trying to change the header from saying "References" to "Works Cited" and insert it on a new blank page.

I tried `\refname` but it did not work, just a blank space in the pdf.  My document is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\bibliography{bibliography}
\begin{document}

Hello World!\autocite{clare2}
\pagebreak
\renewcommand\refname{Works Cited}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Are you missing a `\printbibliography` statement?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`biblatex` uses "bibliography strings" for (among other things) the headings of bibliographies, so redefining `\bibname` (for the `book` and `report` class) or `\refname` (for `article`) won't work. Try to add the following to your preamble:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {Works Cited},
}
```

(And as Mico has noted, you're missing `\printbibliography`.) Compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {Works Cited},% replace "references" with "bibliography"  for `book`/`report`
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]