# biblatex - change formatting of references section title

Tags: sectioning, biblatex

[Trying to Change Bibliography/References Header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56950/4357) explains how to change the name of the section - but I want to change how it's printed.  Any ideas?  The customization I have in mind is quite simple - but this didn't work:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    references = {\hspace{-.82in}References},
}
```

Comment: See here: Define your own header: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41818/section-added-by-addcontentsline-on-the-wrong-page/52829#52829

Comment: That does work, actually.  (Not recommended, but it works.)  If it doesn't work for you, it is because you're doing some 'extra' stuff.  As always, provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Answer (score 3):

Here's something silly that works for me.

```
\section*{\hspace{-.59in}References}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

Comment: You should add your solution to the question and ask if there are better ways.

Comment: I didn't accept the answer - definitely open to seeing a better one!

Comment: Therefor you should provide a MWE.