# Changing from bibliography to references

Tags: biblatex

am using a biblatex style for my thesis with the documentclass{scrrept}. How do i change the heading bibliography to references. i have tried all available option online including the babel approach. Please help me out.

Comment: maybe `\printbibliography[title={References}]` ?

Comment: If this does not help, please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: See also [Trying to Change Bibliography/References Header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/56950/35864)

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using BibLaTeX, and **not** BibTeX

```
\printbibliography[title=References]
```

And for any more questions concerning this and all future questions to this forum, please provide a minimal working example showing your problem at all times. It is hard to guess what might be wrong if you do not see for instance which packages are loaded, what else might have been redefined, and so on.

Comment: For localisation you could also use `\printbibliography[title={\refname}]`